# Primary Key Constraint Violation when trying to insert DISTINCT values

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
insert into MemberGroup (MemberId, MemberGroupId, MemberJoinDate, MemberExpiryDate)
   SELECT DISTINCT 
       TransMemberId, 404, MAX(transaction_time), 
       dateadd(yy,1,MAX(transaction_time))
   FROM 
       DataTrans 
   INNER JOIN 
       DataTransItem ON DataTransId = DataTransItemId
   LEFT JOIN 
       MemberGroup ON MemberId = DataTransItemId
   INNER JOIN 
       MemberMembership ON MemberId = MembershipId
   INNER JOIN 
       LinkedMember ON MembershipId = LinkedMemberId
   WHERE 
       membership_clubid = 1 
       AND TransMemberId IN (select LinkedMemberId from LinkedMember)
       AND TransMemberId IN (select LinkedMemberId from LinkedMember 
                             where MemberGroupId NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
       AND TransMemberId IN (select MemberLinkedId from LinkedMember 
                             where DataTransItemId = 2414)
   GROUP BY 
      TransMemberId
```

Why is this returning the following error even though it uses a distinct within the insert statement as well as groups the `TransMemberId` in the end to select one.

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_MembershipGroup'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.MemberGroup'. The duplicate key value is (FFASED487948KXWC1MH7, 404).

```
DataTransId
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11

TransMemberId
F123TK1TSXX7
F123TK1TSXX7
F123TK1TSXX7
KS723423CLG8LSQ
KS723423CLG8LSQ
KS723423CLG8LSQ
KS723423CLG8LSQ
KS723423CLG8LSQ
48232423KXWC1MH7
48232423KXWC1MH8
48232423KXWC1MH9
F2P3XQTTRJ44232423
F2P3XQTTRJ44232424
F2P3XQTTRJ44232425
F2P3XQTTRJ44232426
F2P3XQTTRJ44232427

DataTransItemId
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11
1.24322E+11

MembershipId
F123TK1TSXX7
F123TK1TSXX7
F123TK1TSXX7
KS723423CLG8LSQ
KS723423CLG8LSQ
KS723423CLG8LSQ
KS723423CLG8LSQ
KS723423CLG8LSQ
48232423KXWC1MH7
48232423KXWC1MH8
48232423KXWC1MH9
F2P3XQTTRJ44232423
F2P3XQTTRJ44232424
F2P3XQTTRJ44232425
F2P3XQTTRJ44232426
F2P3XQTTRJ44232427

LinkedMemberId
F123TK1TSXX7
F123TK1TSXX7
F123TK1TSXX7
KS723423CLG8LSQ
KS723423CLG8LSQ
KS723423CLG8LSQ
KS723423CLG8LSQ
KS723423CLG8LSQ
48232423KXWC1MH7
48232423KXWC1MH7
48232423KXWC1MH7
F2P3XQTTRJ44232423
F2P3XQTTRJ44232423
F2P3XQTTRJ44232423
F2P3XQTTRJ44232423
F2P3XQTTRJ44232423

MemberLinkedId
48KXWC1MH7ASGER
48KXWC1MH7ASGER
48KXWC1MH7ASGER
LKJDJX2RQ26Y7VD
LKJDJX2RQ26Y7VD
LKJDJX2RQ26Y7VD
LKJDJX2RQ26Y7VD
LKJDJX2RQ26Y7VD
F1TK1TSXX723FSDE
F1TK1TSXX723FSDE
F1TK1TSXX723FSDE
Z3VHVL846QQWER
Z3VHVL846QQWER
Z3VHVL846QQWER
Z3VHVL846QQWER
Z3VHVL846QQWER
```

Comment: Is `MemberGroup ` an empty table ? And When you have `GROUP BY` you don't need a `DISTINCT`, And `dateadd(yy,1,MAX(transaction_time))` should come after `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks and no it's not an empty table. I'm trying to insert values into membergroup where a member that is linked in LinkedMember table doesnt already exist in membergroup with id's 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5

Comment: Just to clarify, if I do a select * statement without the inert distinct part we will have multiple records showing up as a result. Any way to select unique member id's only without Group By or Distinct? Can you do UNION on Inner Joins?

Comment: Your results of your select part is not unique? can you give some example data ?

Comment: Why are you inserting transaction_time values into the MemberExpiryDate column?

Comment: Does it matter? Both fields have the same data type of a DATE. If there were errors I would have mentioned :)

Comment: I guess there must be a `FFASED487948KXWC1MH7` _already in the table_

Answer (score 0):

I think your query can be like this:

```
 insert into MemberGroup (MemberId, MemberGroupId, MemberJoinDate, MemberExpiryDate)
 (SELECT TransMemberId , 404, MAX(transaction_time), dateadd(yy,1,MAX(transaction_time))

 FROM DataTrans 
      INNER JOIN DataTransItem ON DataTransId = DataTransItemId
      LEFT JOIN MemberGroup ON MemberId = DataTransItemId
      INNER JOIN MemberMembership ON MemberId = MembershipId
      INNER JOIN LinkedMember ON MembershipId = LinkedMemberId

 WHERE membership_clubid = 1 
      AND TransMemberId IN (select LinkedMemberId from LinkedMember where MemberGroupId NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
      AND TransMemberId IN (select MemberLinkedId from LinkedMember where DataTransItemId = 2414)

 GROUP BY TransMemberId)
```

As you can check; the result of this clue:

```
WHERE TransMemberId IN (select LinkedMemberId from LinkedMember)
    AND TransMemberId IN (select LinkedMemberId from LinkedMember where MemberGroupId NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

is as same as this clue:

```
WHERE TransMemberId IN (select LinkedMemberId from LinkedMember where MemberGroupId NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

Comment: Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.
Also I messed up sorry,The DataTransItemId should be under a different condition as it uses MemberLinkedId (which is pretty much the secondary linked member to the first one)

Comment: @EriadoraOtsito as your edit I change the query and I miss a `)` after group by.

Comment: Nope sorry still trying to insert duplicate values.

Comment: @EriadoraOtsito I need an example of duplicated data ;).

Comment: As you can see you have multiple instances of TransMemberId in there.

Comment: @EriadoraOtsito Thanks, And to clear me, Is `MemberGroupId` an index in your table `MemberGroup ` or not? And also you can add results of your query -that have multiple instances- in your question ;).

Comment: No MemberGroupId is not an index on my table.